# JQuery Datatables Order listener by href in table header

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to create a custom ordering method in my table's header, where there are two elements which each perform an ordering on columns. I'm using a headerCallback to generate the links, and I'm (trying to) attach order.listener() to each of the them so that "Account" orders on the user column, and "Domain" orders on the domain column. I also want to set the user column invisible, but I don't think that will matter here for order.listener function. Maybe I'm missing something easy, but I just don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my test case, and hopefully someone will be able to see it better than me:

```js
        function format(d) {
            return 'Email: ' + d.email + '<br>' +
                'The child row can contain any data you wish, including links, images, inner tables etc.';
        }

$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "headerCallback": function (thead, data, start, end, display) {
                    $(thead).find('th').eq(1).html(
                        '<a href="#" id="sortaccount">Account</a> @ <a href="#" id="sortdomain">Domain</a>'
                    );
                },
    ajax: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesShaver/jsonserver/main/jsonstring.txt",
    columns: [
                {
                    "class": "details-control",
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ""
                },
      
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {                        
                        return  row.user + '@' + row.domain;
                    },
                    "targets": 2
                },

                {
                    data: 'humandiskquota'
                },
                
                {
                  data: 'user'
                },
              
                {
                    data: 'domain'
                },
              {
                data: 'domain',
                visible: false
              }
             
                ]
  });
$('th').off('click');
  table.order.listener( '#sortaccount', 3 );
  table.order.listener( '#sortdomain', 4 );
  
            // Array to track the ids of the details displayed rows
            var detailRows = [];

            $('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
                var idx = $.inArray(tr.attr('id'), detailRows);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    tr.removeClass('details');
                    row.child.hide();

                    // Remove from the 'open' array
                    detailRows.splice(idx, 1);
                } else {
                    tr.addClass('details');
                    row.child(format(row.data())).show();

                    // Add to the 'open' array
                    if (idx === -1) {
                        detailRows.push(tr.attr('id'));
                    }
                }
            });
  
      
  
            // On each draw, loop over the `detailRows` array and show any child rows
            table.on('draw', function () {
                $.each(detailRows, function (i, id) {
                    $('#' + id + ' td.details-control').trigger('click');
                });
            });


            $('#searchInput').on('keyup change', function () {
                table
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            });
            $('#perPage').on('change', function () {
                table.page.len(this.value).draw();
            });

            $('#clearSearch').on('click', function () {
                $('#searchInput').val('');
                table
                    .search('')
                    .draw();
            });

} );
```

```css
        div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_length,
        div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter {
            display: none;
        }

        table.dataTable>thead .sorting:before,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_asc:before,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_desc:before,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
            font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight: 900;
            content: "\f106";
            right: 1.5em;
        }

        table.dataTable>thead .sorting:after,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_asc:after,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_desc:after,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
        table.dataTable>thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after {
            font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight: 900;
            content: "\f107";
            right: .5em;
        }
        table.dataTable td.details-control:after {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight: 900;
            content: "\f0fe";
          color:green;
            right: .5em;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

table.dataTable tr.details td.details-control:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight: 900;
            content: "\f146";
            color:red;
            right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/flatly/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-qF/QmIAj5ZaYFAeQcrQ6bfVMAh4zZlrGwTPY7T/M+iTTLJqJBJjwwnsE5Y0mV7QK" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-primary flex-md-nowrap p-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Test</a>

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control form-control-dark w-1" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="clearSearch" class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <select id="perPage" class="form-control form-control-dark ml-5">
                        <option selected="10">10 per page</option>
                        <option value="25">25 per page</option>
                        <option value="50">50 per page</option>
                        <option value="100">100 per page</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
    </nav>
    <div class=" table-responsive">
      <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Quota</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Domain</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Quota</th>
            <th data-visible="false"></th>
            <th>Domain</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pwstrength-bootstrap/3.0.9/pwstrength-bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-HvxKicgd5m5yRIotHDzL9iFZ2PK/KzyrPqLDYPboT7WQrq3q3NuG+1eWeCZgPru4Pc7fhyPF+71qRQr7mUNWCg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't claim this is a great solution, but it does work:

1. Add an `initComplete` option to your table definition:

```js
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
  $('th').off();
  this.api().order.listener( '#sortaccount', 3 );
  this.api().order.listener( '#sortdomain', 4 );
}
```

This ensures the listeners are added only after the table has finished being rendered - otherwise the listener events may not be added.

2. Also add a separate `on('draw')` event after the table definition:

```js
table.on( 'draw', function () {
  table.order.listener( '#sortaccount', 3 );
  table.order.listener( '#sortdomain', 4 );
} );
```

This is needed because otherwise the listeners are removed after every event - so you need to restore them. This is why my answer is not ideal: I am not sure why this happens.

---

(As an aside, if you place your clickable links outside the table, none of this is needed, and the listeners work the way you would expect them to.)